# Merge line shapefiles into a single shapefile while maintaining integrity of lines that overlap?

Tags: qgis

I have over 300 line shapefiles and I want to merge these files into a single shapefile. I have used merge tool in QGIS, but this tool merges overlapping features into a single feature. I, however, want these features to remain unique even if they do overlap.

Comment: Which _merge_ tool did you use?

Comment: I used 'merge vector layers' of Data Management Tools as well as v.patch of GRASS.

Comment: Have you tried using ogr2ogr with -append? You can loop through all files in a directory. Not sure if that will maintain separate features.

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. Where can I find it?

Comment: ogr2ogr is bundled with QGIS. Fire up the OSGeo4W shell and type ```ogr2ogr``` to get the help. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223183/ogr2ogr-merge-multiple-shapefiles-what-is-the-purpose-of-nln-tag for some examples of usage. This might be the same process as the 'Merge Vector Layers' if QGIS is using the same  tool under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **MMQGIS Plugin**.

- Load all shape files into QGIS (by selecting all before
  it's only one click).
- Use MMQGIS--> Combine --> Merge Layers. Select all (Control + A) and save new shape file.